# Enter inputs only power of 2

Tags: python, input, types

This is an easy question, but I'm stuck.

I am writing a simple program to take an input value which is a distinct multiple of `2`. That is, it must be of the form `2^x`, including `1` which is `2^0=1`.

So, the ONLY valid inputs are `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32,` etc. If the user types input `3`, my program will throw an error. I am also limiting inputs from `1` to `8192` (where `8192 = 2**13`). If the user types `10000` or `-3` or `0`, I throw an error.

This is what I have so far.

```
def checkValue():
maxValue = 8192
while True:
    try:
        intValue = int(input('Please enter integer: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Value must be an integer!")
        continue
    else:
        if intValue < 1:
            print("Value cannot be less than 1")
            continue
        elif intValue > 8192: 
            print("Value cannot be greater than 8192")
            continue
        else:
            return("The value is equal to " + str(intValue) )
```

There must be an easy way to test that the input is a power of `2`. I'm not sure how to incorporate such a test in my current code though. As there are only `14` values I am accepting as valid inputs (i.e 1 and values up to `2**13`), perhaps this is the most efficient test?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a logarithm of base 2 to do so, and check if the number is whole:

```
float.is_integer(math.log(x, 2)) # test if number is whole
```

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Please mark as answer if this is useful to you with the check on the side.

Comment: At the moment, my intValue is inside a function. How can I use what I have entered into the input() later on in the code? At the moment, using `intValue` later on results in an error.

Comment: `return` the value you wish and assign the returned value to a variable.

Comment: Place `return` outside of the first `while` loop and then assign that value to the variable I wish to use later on? So `return intValue` and then `value = intValue`? I will try that

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
def checkValue():
    maxValue = 8192
    while True:
        try:
            intValue = int(input('Please enter integer: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Value must be an integer!")
            continue
        else:
            if intValue in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]:
                return("The value is equal to " + str(intValue))
            elif intValue < 1:
                print("Value cannot be less than 1")
                continue
            elif intValue > 8192: 
                print("Value cannot be greater than 8192")
                continue
            else:
                return("Error")
```

Comment: This was the easiest implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you check if the `log2` of the entered `intValue` is an integer -

```
import math
if int(math.log2(intValue)) == math.log2(intValue):
    return("The value is equal to " + str(intValue) )
else:
    # print error...
```

Example, in case of `intValue` being 32, you'll get `True`, but for 33, you'll get a `False`.

Additionally, you can also check if `math.log2(intValue)` is less than or equal to 13 to satisfy your other constraint of the value being between less than `8192`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test:

```
(math.log(n,2)).is_integer()
```